# Content appearing behind footer with sticky footer CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been using this guide to try to make a sticky footer that will stay at the bottom of a web browser even if there's very little content on the page:
http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

This solution works well on pages with little content, which is good, because it's pages with little content that make it necessary to have a sticky footer in the first place.

Sadly, however, on pages with a decent bit of content (that is, enough to warrant a scroll bar) the sticky footer hovers midway through the webpage, covering up content and text, instead of sticking to the bottom. In these instances, the footer loads in the position it normally would on a page with little content, as opposed to at the bottom, where it should be loading.

Here's an image.

[image]
(had to space out that picture because i'm not high enough rep to post two links.)

The solution I'm using is supposedly pretty effective. I'm a novice at HTML & CSS, so my work is probably atrocious... I'm wondering if I put some sort of conflicting attribute in my CSS file that's wonking everything up. I've fiddled with it and can't seem to find anything.

Here's my CSS:

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /********/height: 100%;
}
#wrap{
width: 100%;
min-width: 550px;
margin: 0 auto;
/**********/min_height: 100%;
/*Code snippet for IE browsers before IE7*/
!--[if lt IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
#wrap { height:100%; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
/*********/position: relative
}
#header{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#000000;
}
#navigationbar{
    background-color:#3B3B3B;
}
#bodytext{
    max-width: 900px;
    min-width: 550px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom:135px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#FFFFFF
}
#footerwrap{
    width:100%;
    height:135px;
    background-color:#000000;
    /****/bottom: 0;
    /****/left: 0;
    /*****/position: absolute;
}
#footer{
    width:740px;
    height:115px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:cambria;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:1em;
}
```

I can post an HTML page if need be.

EDIT: Thanks for the notice. Can't post a link to the site as it's not actually online at this moment, but here's a download link to all the site files in a .zip folder.
http://www.filedropper.com/website_8

To clarify, index.html, services.html, and about.html all have little content and fit fine. Contact.html has a bit more content and is thus the culprit, in this instance.

Comment: can you post a link to your site please. :)

Comment: Just guessing, but try setting a `z-index: -1` to your `#footerwrap`

Comment: We need to see the HTML as well.

Comment: Link to download for the site files posted.

Comment: LcSalazar, thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out and the body text takes priority over the footer and now the footer is covered up, which is no better. What I need is to push the footer down so the two fields aren't overlapping in the first place.

Comment: your container wraper has some type of element being floated inside and does not have a clear:both after it so your footer doesn't know where the above element actually ended